# get google maps v3 area, perimeter and length

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement measuring tools to calculate the area and perimeter of a polygon or the length of a polyline. I've adapted existing code which works with polygons (commented out in the code), but I don't get it to work with both polygons and polylines.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map_div {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=drawing"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), {
    center: {lat: 49.820, lng: 6.100},
    zoom: 8
    });
    // create a dialog box but dont bind it to anything yet    
    // myInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // show drawing tools
    DrawingTools();
}

function DrawingTools() {
    myDrawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: null,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
            ]
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            draggable: true,
            editable: true,
            fillColor: '#fb0a2a',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeColor: '#fb0a2a',
            zIndex: 2000
        },
        polylineOptions: {
            draggable: true,
            editable: true,
            strokeColor: '#fb0a2a',
            zIndex:2000
        }
    });
    myDrawingManager.setMap(map);

    // when polygon drawing is complete, an event is raised by the map
    // this function will listen to the event and work appropriately
    DrawingCompletionListener();
};

/* Code that already works for polygones   
function DrawingCompletionListener() {
    // capture the field, set selector back to hand, remove drawing
    google.maps.event.addListener(
        myDrawingManager,
        'polygoncomplete',
        function(polygon) {
            myField = polygon;
            ShowDrawingTools(false);
            ObjectEditable(false);
            FieldClickListener();
        }
    );
}

*/
// Code I tried to get work for both polygones AND polylines 
function DrawingCompletionListener() {
    // capture the field, set selector back to hand, remove drawing
    google.maps.event.addListener(
        myDrawingManager,
        'overlaycomplete',
        function(event) {
        if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
        function pg (polygon) {
            myField = polygon;
            ShowDrawingTools(false);
            ObjectEditable(false);
            FieldClickListener();
        }}
        else if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
            function pl (polyline) {
            myField = polyline;
            ShowDrawingTools(false);
            ObjectEditable(false);
            AddPropertyToField();
            FieldClickListener();
        }}
        }
    );
}

/**
 * Show or hide drawing tools
 */
function ShowDrawingTools(val) {
    myDrawingManager.setOptions({
        drawingMode: null,
        drawingControl: val
    });
}

/**
 * Allow or disallow polygon/polyline to be editable and draggable 
 */
function ObjectEditable(val) {
    myField.setOptions({
        editable: val,
        draggable: val
    });
    myInfoWindow.close();
    return false;
}

/**
 * Attach an event listener to the polygon/polyline. When a user clicks on the 
 * object, get a formatted message that contains links to re-edit the 
 * object, mark it as complete, or delete it. The message
 * appears as a dialog box
 */
function FieldClickListener() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(
        myField,
        'click',
        function(event) {
            var message = GetMessage(myField);
            myInfoWindow.setOptions({ content: message });
            myInfoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
            myInfoWindow.open(map);
        }
    );
}

/**
 * Delete the polygon and show the drawing tools so that new polygon can be
 * created
 */
function DeleteField() {
    myInfoWindow.close();
    myField.setMap(null);
    ShowDrawingTools(true);
}

/**
 * Get coordinates of the polygon/polyline and display information that should 
 * appear in the polygons dialog box when it is clicked
 */
function GetMessage(polygon) {
    var coordinates = polygon.getPath().getArray();
    var message = '';

    message += '<div>' 
        + 'area : ~' + GetArea(polygon) + ' ar<br />'
        + 'perimeter : ~' + GetPerimeter(polygon) + ' m'
        + 'length : ~' + GetLength(polyline) + ' m'
        + '</div>';

    message += '<hr><div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="PolygonEditable(true);">Edit</button>'
        + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="ObjectEditable(false);">OK</button>'
        + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="DeleteField(myField);">Löschen</button></div>';

    return message;
}

/**
 * Get area / perimeter of the drawn polygon
 */
function GetArea(poly) {
    var result = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(poly.getPath()))/100;
    return result.toFixed(2);
}
function GetPerimeter(poly) {
    var perimeter = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(poly.getPath()));
    return perimeter.toFixed(0);
}
function GetLenght(poly) {
    var length = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(poly.getPath()));
    return length.toFixed(0);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

<div id="map_div">
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I've added the missing map object and it's initialisation, so the code should work.

Comment: Should work?  Or does work?  The point of an [mcve] is that you have verified that it exhibits your issue.  I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` with the posted code.

Comment: Now I added a complete and minimal example that demonstrates my issues. I can draw polygons and polylines, but I don't get the area/perimeter and length. Only when I reduce the DrawingCompletionListener() to polygons (commented out in the provided code and comment out   the line : + 'length : ~' + GetLength(polyline) + ' m' , the code works for polygons.

Comment: Not sure why you change what you are doing in the overlay complete function.  You are defining functions, but not calling them (you probably just want to execute the body of the function there, rather than defining a function and calling it.  When I fix that, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: myInfoWindow is not defined(…)`, and when I define `myInfoWindow`, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: AddPropertyToField is not defined(…)`

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the 'DrawingCompletionListener()' function to work.

I still have a little problem. I want to display different informations depending on the type of object, that is drawn. I don't get the correct syntax in my GetMessage(obj)-function to check whether the obj is a polygon or a polyline?
Here the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map_div {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=drawing"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), {
    center: {lat: 49.820, lng: 6.100},
    zoom: 8
    });
    // create a dialog box but dont bind it to anything yet    
    myInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // show drawing tools
    DrawingTools();
}

function DrawingTools() {
    myDrawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: null,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
            ]
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            draggable: true,
            editable: true,
            fillColor: '#fb0a2a',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeColor: '#fb0a2a',
            zIndex: 2000
        },
        polylineOptions: {
            draggable: true,
            editable: true,
            strokeColor: '#fb0a2a',
            zIndex:2000
        }
    });
    myDrawingManager.setMap(map);

    // when polygon drawing is complete, an event is raised by the map
    // this function will listen to the event and work appropriately
    DrawingCompletionListener();
};    

// Draw polygones or polylines and add clicklistener to open infoWindow 
function DrawingCompletionListener() {
    // capture the field, set selector back to hand, remove drawing
    google.maps.event.addListener(
        myDrawingManager,
        'overlaycomplete',
        function(event) {
        if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
            myField = event.overlay;  
            ShowDrawingTools(false);
            ObjectEditable(false);
            FieldClickListener(); 
        }
        else if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
            myField = event.overlay;
            ShowDrawingTools(false);
            ObjectEditable(false);
            FieldClickListener();
    }
        }
    );
}


/**
 * Show or hide drawing tools
 */
function ShowDrawingTools(val) {
    myDrawingManager.setOptions({
        drawingMode: null,
        drawingControl: val
    });
}

/**
 * Allow or disallow polygon/polyline to be editable and draggable 
 */
function ObjectEditable(val) {
    myField.setOptions({
        editable: val,
        draggable: val
    });
    myInfoWindow.close();
    return false;
}

/**
 * Attach an event listener to the polygon/polyline. When a user clicks on the 
 * object, get a formatted message that contains links to re-edit the 
 * object, mark it as complete, or delete it. The message
 * appears as a dialog box
 */
function FieldClickListener() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(
        myField,
        'click',
        function(event) {
            var message = GetMessage(myField);
            myInfoWindow.setOptions({ content: message });
            myInfoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
            myInfoWindow.open(map);
        }
    );
}

/**
 * Delete the polygon / polyline and show the drawing tools again
 */
function DeleteField() {
    myInfoWindow.close();
    myField.setMap(null);
    ShowDrawingTools(true);
}

/**
 * Display information that should 
 * appear in the polygons / polylines dialog box when it is clicked
 */
function GetMessage(obj) {
    var message = '';

    // this is not yet working
    if (obj.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
        message += '<div>' 
        + 'area : ' + GetArea(obj) + ' ar<br />'
        + 'perimeter : ' + GetLength(obj) + ' m <br />'
        + '</div>';
    }
    else if (obj.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
        message += '<div>' 
        + 'length : ' + GetLength(obj) + ' m <br />'
        + '</div>';
    }

    message += '<hr><div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="ObjectEditable(true);">Edit</button>'
        + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="ObjectEditable(false);">OK</button>'
        + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="DeleteField(myField);">Delete</button></div>';

    return message;
}

/**
 * Get area / perimeter / lenght of the drawn polygon / polyline
 */
function GetArea(obj) {
    var result = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(obj.getPath()))/100;
    return result.toFixed(2);
}
function GetLength(obj) {
       var length = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(obj.getPath()));
    return length.toFixed(0);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

<div id="map_div">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```